# Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, development-environment

I'm looking to test my app on different types and versions of mobile. I am trying to find an emulator that will allow me to choose different mobiles and different versions of Androids. What would be the best program to use for this?

I was looking into Genymotion but it doesn't have the playstore which I would like to be included.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bluestack as it provide Playstore option with it

Comment: But it does not allow me to choose a different mobile phone type or android version. That is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The updated emulators that came with the new update to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/studio.html) are very satisfying.

I also used Genymotion before, but the new AVD manager is a lot more complete and has numerous extra functionalities.

You can download [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) here

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Xamarin Android Player](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player), it is blazing fast (2x Android default emulator). You just need to download and install [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), that is a free virtual machine, before [getting started](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/).